# I tried to test but there is import test error, so what is the problem?

Tags: django

https://github.com/Angelheartha/tera ↓
i did python manage.pytest polls
↓
(venv) C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject22\mysite\mysite\mysite>python manage.py text polls Unknown command: 'text'. Did you mean test? Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

(venv) C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject22\mysite\mysite\mysite>python manage.py test polls System check identified no issues (0 silenced). E ERROR: mysite.mysite.mysite.polls (unittest.loader._FailedTest) ImportError: Failed to import test module: mysite.mysite.mysite.polls Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 470, in _find_test_path package = self._get_module_from_name(name) File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name import(name) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.mysite'

Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)

(venv) C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject22\mysite\mysite\mysite>cd mysite/mysite

but

test is imported on polls/text.py

so i dont get what is the problem .....

Comment: Just run `python manage.py test` on the folder that has manage.py file.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).